# How to change html class after ajax successful response?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle the voting arrow class, the same way as stackoverflow's voting arrow. For a logged in user, if already voted up, the html is:

```
<a href="#vote" id="vote-up-%1$d" class="vote vote-up-on"></a>
<a href="#vote" id="vote-down-%1$d" class="vote vote-down-off"></a>
```

After user clicked down arrow,  if response success, How to change "vote-up-on" to "vote-up-off", and change "vote-down-off" to "vote-down-one"?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: give us some javascript code so that we could see you have scratched your head before posting question here

Comment: what you mean by "if response success"? i see no ajax posted in your question.

Comment: I mostly tried toggler. my code is full of splitting ajax response message, it'd be a bit messy post it here. I mentioned ajax just because it's all over my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a callback function when you receive Ajax response.

```
function addVoteUpClass() {
    if (jQuery(".vote").hasClass("vote-up-on")) {
        jQuery(".vote-up-on").removeClass("vote-up-on").addClass("vote-up-off");
    }
}

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "your_url",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        addVoteUpClass();
    }
});
```

Comment: Amazing! I added the statement (without function wrapper) inside my ajax response function, and it works!

Answer (score 4):

Well, this works the same as the SA votes - it could be a bit more concise but I really need to get back to work ;-)

```
<a href="#vote" id="vote-up-%1$d" class="vote vote-up">vote up</a>
<span class="votes">0</span>
<a href="#vote" id="vote-down-%1$d" class="vote vote-down">vote down</a>
```

and the jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.vote-up', function () {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('vote-locked')){     
        var votes = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.votes').text());  
        if(!$(this).hasClass('vote-off')){

            $(this).addClass('vote-off');
            $(this).nextAll('a').addClass('vote-locked');
            votes++;

        }
        else{

            $(this).removeClass('vote-off');
            $(this).nextAll('a').removeClass('vote-locked');
            votes--;

        }
       $(this).parent().find('.votes').text(votes);
   }
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.vote-down', function () {
     if(!$(this).hasClass('vote-locked')){  
        var votes = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.votes').text());  
        if(!$(this).hasClass('vote-off')){

            $(this).addClass('vote-off');
            $(this).prevAll('a').addClass('vote-locked');
            votes--;

        }
        else{

            $(this).removeClass('vote-off');
            $(this).prevAll('a').removeClass('vote-locked');
            votes++;

        }
       $(this).parent().find('.votes').text(votes);
    }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gqDgL/

Comment: Thanks! This works for clicking down arrow. I tried to copy your code and add another 2 line for up arrow, but my addition for up arrow not working. Would you please show how to make it for both arrow?

Comment: could it be that vote-down-one should be vote-down-on? OR vote-up-on should be vote-up-one?

Comment: No, I changed vote-down-one to "on", I knew that's a spelling thing.

Comment: Please also consider there are situations when a user never voted, both arrows are off, when a user voted up, then up-on and down-off, when a user voted down, then, up-off and down-on.

Comment: I think you can take my answer and edit that last part in ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the update! But it still works for the down arrow, not work if click up arrow :-(

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble. The code need to be initially set "off or on" base on user's history record. So, I can't use "vote-up" and "vote-down". I must use either "vote-up-on"/"vote-up-off" for up , either "vote-down-on"/"vote-down-off" for down.

Comment: well you can use class="vote vote-up vote-off" or similar - but I think you can go on on your own from here...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can add and remove classes, using addClass and removeClass,

```
$('#vote-up-%1$d').removeClass('vote-up-on');

$('#vote-up-%1$d').addClass('vote-up-off');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#vote-up").click(function () {
            $(this).toggle();
            $(this).toggleClass("vote vote-down-off");
        });
```

try this